# Karate windows locator am trying to automate windows application using robot

Tags: karate

Using selenium am able to click the element using xpath "//bwc-bttn[@icon='question']"

when I use same xpath in karate robot test getting failed. Am using inspect.exe to inspect element there in no Id/name present in the application

Comment: I have no other suggestions for such an open-ended question. please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot#windows-locators